# when the data is 0 show blank else the value in concat funtion

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
CONCAT(ISNULL(NES.NumberOfNomination, ''), ' / ', ISNULL(TP.NoOfSeats, '')) as Seats,
```

when the `TP.noOfseats` is `0` I want the column blank in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
CASE TP.noOfseats 
     WHEN 0 THEN ''
     ELSE CONCAT(ISNULL(NES.NumberOfNomination, ''), 
                 ' / ', 
                 ISNULL(TP.NoOfSeats, ''))
END AS Seats
```

Comment: @Ahaliya care to be more specific?

Answer (score -1):

```
CONCAT(ISNULL(NES.NumberOfNomination, ''), ' / ', 
       ISNULL(CASE WHEN TP.NoOfSeats = 0 
                   THEN '' 
                   ELSE TP.NoOfSeats END, '')
       ) as Seats,
```